# How to make scroll bar scrollable with mousewheel on tkinter when the mouse cursor is anywhere on the screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I added scroll bar in a frame when the entry grid boxes exceeds the height of the frame. The scroll bar can be dragged and mouse wheel works when the cursor is hovering in the area of scroll bar but when the cursor is elsewhere, it doesn't work. How to make the scrolling possible when cursor is anywhere on the screen?

```
from tkinter import *

def data():
    for i in range(50):
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            l4 = Label(frame, text="Size of rectangle:")
            l4.grid(row=i, column=0)
        en = Entry(frame)
        en.grid(row=i, column=1)
    b3 = Button(frame, text="Save")
    b3.grid(row=51, column=0)
    b4 = Button(frame, text="Back")
    b4.grid(row=51, column=1)


def myfunction(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=600,height=600)

root=Tk()
sizex = 650
sizey = 625
posx  = 100
posy  = 100
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))

myframe=Frame(root,relief=GROOVE,width=200,height=200,bd=1)
myframe.place(x=20,y=20)


canvas=Canvas(myframe)
frame=Frame(canvas)
myscrollbar=Scrollbar(myframe,orient="vertical",command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)

myscrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left")
canvas.create_window((0,0),window=frame,anchor='nw')
frame.bind("<Configure>",myfunction)
data()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)
...
def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
    self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1*(event.delta/120), "units")

What should I write on mine?

Comment: If you want that scrollbar to move as long as you are scrolling inside the GUI, then bind it to `root`.

Comment: I did this : def _on_mousewheel(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(-1*(event.delta/120), "units")   
canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)

and got errors.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sel\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-82-10d2848de77b>", line 19, in _on_mousewheel
    canvas.yview_scroll(-1*(event.delta/120), "units")
  File "C:\Users\sel\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1751, in yview_scroll
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'yview', 'scroll', number, what)
_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "1.0"

Comment: If you read through that post you should find your answer.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.